# Pyspark dataframe explode string column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for an efficient way to explode the rows in the pyspark dataframe `df_input` into columns. I dont understand that format `'@{name...}'` and don't know where to start in order to decode it. Thanks for help!

```
df_input = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, '@{name= Hans; age= 45}'), 
        (2, '@{name= Jeff; age= 15}'), 
        (3, '@{name= Elona; age= 23}')
    ], 
    ('id', 'firstCol')
      )
```

expected result:

```
+---+-----+---+
| id| name|age|
+---+-----+---+
|  1| Hans| 45|
|  2| Jeff| 15|
|  3|Elona| 23|
+---+-----+---+
```

Comment: What data types do you see when you use `df.printSchema()` on your real dataframe?

Comment: The data type is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string into map type using [`str_to_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#str_to_map) function, explode it then pivot the keys:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df_input.selectExpr(
    "id",
    "explode(str_to_map(regexp_replace(firstCol, '[@{}]', ''), ';', '='))"
).groupby("id").pivot("key").agg(F.first("value"))

df.show()
#+---+----+------+
#|id | age|name  |
#+---+----+------+
#|1  | 45 | Hans |
#|2  | 15 | Jeff |
#|3  | 23 | Elona|
#+---+----+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract

df_input.select( 
 df_input.id, #id
 regexp_extract( #use regex
  df_input.firstCol, #on firstCol
  '\s(.*);', #find a space character then capture a (group of text) until you find a ';'
  1 # use capture group 1 as text
 ).alias("name"), 
 regexp_extract(
  df_input.firstCol, 
  '\s.*\s(.*)}', #find the second space then capture a (group  of text) until you find a '}'
  1 # use capture group 1 as text
 ).alias("age") 
).show()
+---+-----+---+
| id| name|age|
+---+-----+---+
|  1| Hans| 45|
|  2| Jeff| 15|
|  3|Elona| 23|
+---+-----+---+
```